# Recover the Windows bootloader on a PC that cannot boot from USB or DVD

Tags: windows-7, boot, bootloader

I have a HDD with a Windows 7 installation, but without the bootloader. The Windows installation is for a different computer than mine. That computer's BIOS is either broken or very old, and I can't boot from USB or DVD. What I can do is connecting that drive to my PC, either via USB or via SATA.

Is it possible to recover the bootloader, so that the other, old PC will be able to boot the Windows on the HDD?

**Details:** We wanted to perform a clean reinstall of Windows 7 on a friend's PC. The original setup was a 500GB HDD, with a 90GB partition with the Windows 7 installation (p1), and a 400GB data partition (p2). As we couldn't boot from USB or DVD, despite our best efforts, we decided to clean the two partitions of it's 500Gb HDD separately. We formatted p2 and installed Windows 7 on it using the existing Win7 on p1. Then, we booted from p2, and formatted p1. Bad idea, as we didn't realize that the bootloader was also on P1... so after a reboot we got stuck. Lacking a better idea, we removed the HDD, and I took it home to try whatever I can do. My PC can boot from USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer, but this was our solution:
I plugged the HDD in my computer, formatted and installed a new Win7 Ultimate. Then I used the *Sysprep* utility to make it bootable on my friend's PC. This removes all PC-specific settings from a clean,  freshly installed Win7 installation and generalizes it to be usable on arbitary PC.

My method was based on [theeldergeek.com](http://www.theeldergeek.com/windows_7/imaging_windows_7_6.htm):

> 1. Clean install Win7 on the HDD, and boot it. Don't do anything other than the mandatory setups.
> 2. After you're through the setup, click Start. In the Search box type `C:\Windows\System32\sysprep\sysprep.exe` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to
>    start Sysprep.
> 3. In *System Cleanup Action* dropdown list select *Enter System Out-Of-Box Experience (OOBE)*.
> 4. Place a checkmark in the *Generalize* check box.
> 5. In *Shutdown Options* dropdown list select *Shutdown*.
> 6. Click *OK* button to shut down the computer.

Note that after this, the Win7 installation remains generalized only until it boots again, then it sets itself up to the computer it booted on. After this, you have to *generalize* it again. Be aware though that you can generalize a Windows installation only a limited number of times (maybe 6?), after this you have to reinstall it. Generalizing also deactivates the installation.