# My windows incorrectly thinks it's installed on USB - How to change this?

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootloader

I'm running Windows 10 Professional, and I'd like to install the latest Insider build. I'm not on an Insider build right now.

Due to reasons I don't discuss here, recently I moved my bootloader to an external USB hard drive with Windows 7 and no bootloader using EasyBCD. (It didn't work... :) ) Since then, I moved it back, even recreated it a few times, but my Windows still believes it is on an USB disc.

This prevents me from installing Insider builds, as I get an error about "Windows can't be installed on an USB drive via the installer." (Free translation of mine.) How do I reset the original state and make Windows belive the correct thing, that it's installed on my C: SSD?

Comment: It is a single registry key.  Mothers computer had the same problem after I migrated her hdd to a   See duplicate for more information

Comment: *"Due to reasons I don't discuss here (though you have a clue..."*  I don't have a clue.  Please enlighten me.

Comment: @Ramhound Great find, thank you! Different question, same problem and solution.

Comment: @Run5k it's my [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1247350/recover-the-windows-bootloader-on-an-hdd-of-another-pc)... (Excuse me, I just find my whole struggle a little ironic.)

Comment: @Neinstein Every question is unique.  If you don't want to discuss a previous question don't mention anything to reference it.  Only time we would go searching for it is if , research results themselves, brought it to our attention.

Comment: @Run5k you're right, I removed the reference.